# How do you change the color of commands entered at the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the color of input commands at the terminal in VS Code. It seems that the default color used by all themes is `terminal.ansiBrightYellow`, which is `#b5ba00`. The only way I see to change it is to change the value of that color in settings:

[image]

Uncommenting the change to `terminal.ansiBrightYellow` effectively changes the color of the command:

[image]

This demonstrates that somewhere VS Code is setting the color of text entered at the terminal to `terminal.ansiBrightYellow`. Where can I find and how can I change that setting?

Note that this is different from the `terminal.foreground` setting, which doesn't affect user-entered text.

I'm on Windows using PowerShell, but I'm not sure that makes any difference.